# xref-find-apropos vs vc-git-grep

Tags: helm, git, xref, vc-git-grep

I 've been using `git` specific commands from helm (I think it internally uses `vc-git-grep`

I find `xref-find-definitions` work very well. and wonder how `xref-find-apropos` compare with `vc-git-grep`

I coulnd't find `git` specific commands from `xref-find-apropos` but I might have overlooked something.

Which one is preferable to find some symbols (not necessarily definitions) in a project?

---

Edit

Never mind, xref-find-apropos uses TAG file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is `vc-git-grep` is always a textual search which will give you matches against all lines in the checked in files.

`xref-find-apropos` searches for function definitions (and other declarations) with names that match the pattern. But not text inside comments, or even implementation code.

And it delegates the search to the current Xref backend. If the backend uses TAGS (the default one), then it uses TAGS. Otherwise, it uses something else (like the LSP protocol, for example).